# How to move a MS Word table horizontally programmatically

Tags: c#, ms-word

I know that paragraphs in a word document can moved horizontally by changing the left indent like this:

`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.LeftIndent = 15.`

However, it's not the same of tables; I couldn't find indent property for tables or any other way to move them. So, my equation is how can I move a table horizontally using c#?

Comment: maybe you should specify your version of Word and the type of program you are working on

Comment: Thanks Patrick. How about for inserted pictures?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question.  If my answer helped you you should mark it as accepted, you can do this by clicking the tick mark beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, you can use

```
Selection.Tables(1).Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=15.0, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
```

so in C# it will be something like this:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.SetLeftIndent(15.0,
    wdAdjustNone)
```